# Why is fscanf read garbage?

Tags: gcc, scanf, codeblocks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define PATH "F:\\c\\projects\\Banking Management System\\data\\"
#define F_ACCT "accounts.txt"
#define FILENAME(file)  PATH file

#define F_ACCT_FPRINTF "%05d%-8s%-30s%d%d%d%-20s%-20s%-20s%c%-15.2lf\n"
#define F_ACCT_FSCANF  "%05d%8s%30[^\n]%d%d%d%20[^\n]%20[^\n]%20[^\n]%c%lf\n"

typedef struct Date
{
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int ccyy;
} Date;

typedef struct Account
{
    int id;
    char acct_no[8];
    char name[30];
    Date birthday;
    char telephone_no[20];
    char mobile_no[20];
    char tfn[20];
    char acct_type;   // 'S' - Saving | 'C' - Current | Fixed - 'F' | Recurring - 'R'
    double acct_bal;
} Account;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Account *ac_t=malloc(sizeof(Account));

    if (ac_t==NULL)
    {
        free(ac_t);
        perror("Fatal error: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE *fp=fopen(FILENAME(F_ACCT),"a+"); // Save option selected by the user

    if (!fp)              // NULL=0=true
    {
        free(ac_t);
        perror("ERROR:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    (fscanf(fp,F_ACCT_FSCANF,\
            &ac_t->id,\
            ac_t->acct_no,\
            ac_t->name,\
            &ac_t->birthday.dd,\
            &ac_t->birthday.mm,\
            &ac_t->birthday.ccyy,\
            ac_t->telephone_no,\
            ac_t->mobile_no,\
            ac_t->tfn,\
            &ac_t->acct_type,\
            &ac_t->acct_bal));

    printf("\ntmp=%d", tmp);
    printf("\n[%d]",ac_t->id);
    printf("\n[%s]",ac_t->acct_no);
    printf("\n[%s]",ac_t->name);
    printf("\n[%d]",ac_t->birthday.dd);
    printf("\n[%d]",ac_t->birthday.mm);
    printf("\n[%d]",ac_t->birthday.ccyy);
    printf("\n[%s]",ac_t->telephone_no);
    printf("\n[%s]",ac_t->mobile_no);
    printf("\n[%s]",ac_t->tfn);
    printf("\n[%c]",ac_t->acct_type);
    printf("\n[%lf]",ac_t->acct_bal);
    system("pause");

    free(pw_t);

    return 0;

}
```

=========================================================================================

**Input file (accounts.txt)**
**=========================**

```
000011000    Anil Dhar                     27111960(02) 8883 2827      0408 942 407        111222333           S         100.21   

Note: The record was created successfully using frpintf() as per F_ACCT_FPRINTF.

**Problem**
=======

fscanf is reading garbage values like this:

ac_t->id 1
t_acct_no
name Anil Dhar
birthday.dd 27
birthday.mm 11
birthday.ccyy 1960
telephone_no (02) 8883 2827      0408 942 407        111222333           Sogram Files\Intel\ip¬tαK4
mobile_no 0408 942 407        111222333           Sogram Files\Intel\ip¬tαK4
tfn 111222333           Sogram Files\Intel\ip¬tαK4
t_acct_type
acct_bal 74895632819821970000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

All my string variables like name, telephone_no, mobile_no, tfn could contain spaces.
The record is not delimited with anything. My fscanf() is not populating the fields properly wherever I am reading the string variables.

What could have gone wrong????

Comment: Correction:
#define F_ACCT_FSCANF  "%05d%8[^\n]%30[^\n]%02d%02d%04d%20[^\n]%20[^\n]%20[^\n]%c%15.2lf\n"

Comment: Using `fscanf` to read this kind of data is a horrible idea, but your immediate problem is character buffer overflow. `char name[30];` can only contain a string of length 29 max, because every string has a null delimiter, but you are trying to stuff a string of length 30 in there. Same about all the other `char [...]` fields.

Comment: `%20[^\n]` it's reading up until a newline, so it's reading _everything_ up until a end of line. It looks like fields are separated by spaces, in your case. What is the input format?

Comment: Input format is F_ACCT_FPRINTF

Comment: @KamilCuk The input format is defined in F_ACCT_PRINTF as preprocessor directive. THANKS

Comment: `The input format is defined in F_ACCT_PRINTF` No, you are using `fscanf(fp,F_ACCT_FSCANF,`, and in `F_ACCT_FSCANF` there's `%20[^\n]` to which my comment applies. In your code `F_ACCT_PRINTF` is unused.

Comment: @KamilCuk you are right. My fields aren't separated by any thing. Spaces appear naturally according to a field's Value.

Comment: @KamilCuk There are many fields that may contain spaces as a part of their value. How could I read such a record?

Comment: Up until a space. `%20[^ ]`

Answer (score 0):

`$20[^\n]` reads everything up until end of line. Read up until a space, for example. Note that all specifiers except `%[]` and `%c` automatically eat and ignore leading whitespaces (tabs, newlines and spces). Note that all whitespaces automatically eat and ignore zero or more whitespaces. See scanf documentation. I would also sprinkle spaces anyway to make `scanf` format more readable. Do not add trailing `\n`. Check return value of scanf, do not leave it unchecked - scanning may fail. You need to at max read one character less than your buffers, or you have to increase your buffers by one - place for terminating zero byte.

```
"%d %7[^ ] %29[^ ] %d %d %d %19[^ ] %19[^ ] %19[^ ] %c %lf"
```

Answer (score 0):

`%s` reads whitespace delimited strings, while `%[^\n]` reads up to the next newline.  It appears that you want a specific number of characters, so you want `%c`.  So you should have something more like:

```
#define F_ACCT_FSCANF "%5d%8c%30c%2d%2d%4d%20c%20c%20c%c%lf"
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly correct, because your printing format is somewhat ambiguous (using `%d` rather than `%02d` means you don't know how many digits you'll get).  It also will go off the rails badly if your input file had its spacing modified in any way, so you might want to use fgets+sscanf rather than fscanf, as that will at least allow you to resynchronize after any corrupted line.

One thing to be careful of -- `%8c` will read *exactly* 8 characters into the buffer provided as an argument with NO terminating NUL -- if you want NUL terminated strings, you'll need to arrange for that manually.